# vala: Serializing object property with Json.gobject_serialize?

Tags: json, vala, gobject

I need to save an object's state into a file and retrieve it later. I found JSON serialization would help and found this method `Json.gobject_serialize`. Using this method, I can successfully serialize objects containing string properties. But what should I do, if the object A consists of another object (say B) within it and I need to serialize object A.

## EDIT

What should I do if the object A consists of array (say B) of objects?
I created a small test program for this purpose and I failed in that try. I cannot find any detailed documentation about JSON Serialization for vala.

```
public class Foo : Object {

    public int iFoo {get; set;}
    public string sFoo {get; set;}

    Bar[] _bar = {};
    public Bar[] bar {get {return _bar;} set{_bar = value;}}

    public class Bar : Object {
        public int iBar {get; set;}
        public string sBar {get; set;}

        construct {
            iBar = 02;
            sBar = "OutOfRange";
        }
    }

    construct {
        _bar += new Bar();

        iFoo = 74;
        sFoo = "GIrafee";
    }

    public static int main () {
        Json.Node root = Json.gobject_serialize (new Foo());

        Json.Generator generator = new Json.Generator ();
        generator.set_root (root);
        stdout.printf(generator.to_data (null) + "\n");

        return 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Serialization with JSON-GLib is recursive for properties containing complex types.

If the property of a GObject contains another GObject, `json_gobject_serialize()` will recursively call `json_gobject_serialize()` on the instance stored inside the property — or serialize the `null` if the property is unset.

Comment: What should I do in case I have an array of Objects or array of any basic type

Comment: Vala compound/generic types do not have a mapping in GObject; you need to implement your own serialization by implementing the JsonSerializable interface.

Comment: Here's an example of SList serialization: https://github.com/major-lab/json-api-glib/blob/master/src/json-api-object.vala

Answer (score 2):

I've implemented a object to support Json.Serializable interface as follow:

```
    public class DbObject : GLib.Object, Json.Serializable
    {
        public Json.Object? meta { get; construct set; default = null; }
        public VersionSync version { get; set; default = VersionSync.UNKNOWN; }

        public virtual Value get_property (ParamSpec pspec)
        {
            Value prop_value = GLib.Value(pspec.value_type);
            (this as GLib.Object).get_property(pspec.name, ref prop_value);
            stdout.printf ("%s --> %s\n", prop_value.type_name(), prop_value.strdup_contents());

            return prop_value;
        }

        public virtual void set_property (ParamSpec pspec, Value value)
        {
            (this as GLib.Object).set_property (pspec.name, value);
        }

        public unowned ParamSpec? find_property (string name)
        {
            return ((ObjectClass) get_type ().class_ref ()).find_property (name);
        }

        public virtual Json.Node serialize_property (string property_name, Value @value, ParamSpec pspec)
        {
            if (@value.type ().is_a (typeof (Json.Object)))
            {
                var obj = @value as Json.Object;
                if (obj != null)
                {
                    var node = new Json.Node (NodeType.OBJECT);
                    node.set_object (obj);
                    return node;
                }
            }
            else if (@value.type ().is_a (typeof (Gee.ArrayList)))
            {
                unowned Gee.ArrayList<GLib.Object> list_value = @value as Gee.ArrayList<GLib.Object>;
                if (list_value != null || property_name == "data")
                {
                    var array = new Json.Array.sized (list_value.size);
                    foreach (var item in list_value)
                    {
                        array.add_element (gobject_serialize (item));
                    }

                    var node = new Json.Node (NodeType.ARRAY);
                    node.set_array (array);
                    return node;
                }
            }
            else if (@value.type ().is_a (typeof (GLib.Array)))
            {
                unowned GLib.Array<GLib.Object> array_value = @value as GLib.Array<GLib.Object>;
                if (array_value != null || property_name == "data")
                {
                    var array = new Json.Array.sized (array_value.length);
                    for (int i = 0; i < array_value.length; i++) {
                        array.add_element (gobject_serialize (array_value.index(i)));
                    }

                    var node = new Json.Node (NodeType.ARRAY);
                    node.set_array (array);
                    return node;
                }
            }            
            else if (@value.type ().is_a (typeof (HashTable)))
            {
                var obj = new Json.Object ();
                var ht_string = @value as HashTable<string, string>;
                if (ht_string != null)
                {
                    ht_string.foreach ((k, v) => {
                        obj.set_string_member (k, v);
                    });

                    var node = new Json.Node (NodeType.OBJECT);
                    node.set_object (obj);
                    return node;
                } else {
                    var ht_object = @value as HashTable<string, GLib.Object>;
                    if (ht_object != null)
                    {
                        ht_object.foreach ((k, v) => {
                            obj.set_member (k, gobject_serialize (v));
                        });    

                        var node = new Json.Node (NodeType.OBJECT);
                        node.set_object (obj);
                        return node;
                    }
                }
            }

            return default_serialize_property (property_name, @value, pspec);
        }

        public virtual bool deserialize_property (string property_name, out Value @value, ParamSpec pspec, Json.Node property_node)
        {
            return default_deserialize_property (property_name, out @value, pspec, property_node);
        }
    }
```